# TextView does not wrap lines

Tags: android

I need to place text on image. If the text is too long it should wrap to new line. I use RelativeLayout this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myPicture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myPicture"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/myPicture"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/myPicture" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This works as expected on Android 4.1.2 but on 4.3 and 4.4 the text is not wrapped. I have to mention that I use custom style to support action bar.

```
<style name="MyActionBarTheme"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
</style>
```

I have tried setting

```
android:singleLine="false"
android:ellipsize="none"
android:maxLines="100"
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
```

without success. Is there any other way to display multiline text on image?

Comment: try giving a fixed width to TextView

Comment: Have you tried width = match_parent for the textview?

Comment: I have tried TextView with android:layout_width="match_parent"

Answer (score -1):

try changing `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Answer (score -1):

Try `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`.

Comment: And the answer by ihsan does?